# expo-payments-stripe module fails after compilation into standalone apk

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, stripe-payments

I've added a simple payment system into my Expo managed workflow app, but it acts quirky. The payments do perfectly work (even with the live keys, charging actual money) in development mode. Anyways, I noticed the payment system simply stops working as expected after compilation. This is how the app is integrating the payment module:

```
import { PaymentsStripe as Stripe } from 'expo-payments-stripe';

// irrelevant code

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        try {
            await Stripe.setOptionsAsync({
                publishableKey: 'PUBLIC_KEY',
            });
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    }

// irrelevant code

                try {
                    const token = await Stripe.createTokenWithCardAsync(params);
                    alert(token);
                    console.log(token);
                    this.queryServer(token);
                } catch (err) {
                    // throw err;
                    alert(err);
                }

// irrelevant code
```

Although there are no errors being shown in development mode, after being compiled, the installed app alerts the first following error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating: 'v.init')`, which is followed by this next alert error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'v.createTokenWithCard')`.

I saw some people complaining about the fact that the `expo-payments-stripe` module does not work in the managed workflow, but, as I read from the Expo documentation (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/payments/), it only is the case it does not work for ios in the managed workflow, Android should be fine. Maybe I got it wrong?